# Precise meaning of H-admissible for a normal subgroup H of a group G

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, normal-subgroups

In the proof of Robinson's "A course in the theory of groups", 3.1.8 (theorem due to Wilson) he mentions H-admissible subgroups, but without, afaik, defining that.

In this context, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of finite index, and we are assuming that $G$ satisfies min-$n$ but $H$ doesn't satisfy min-$n$ (for contradiction, since we are trying to prove $H$ does in fact satisfy min-$n$.)  Here min-$n$ is the property of a group that it has no infinite, strictly descending chain of normal subgroups.  So far so good.

Then without explanation he asserts "Now $H$ does not satisfy min$H$, the minimal condition on $H$-admissible subgroups," but I don't know the meaning of "$H$-admissible subgroups." The concept is then used in the long proof that I haven't yet understood - so any help would be appreciated.

For context, the next sentence is "By min-$n$ [on G, I suppose] if follows that $H$ contains a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ which is minimal with respect to not satisfying min$H$."  So I think we are going to take a strictly decreasing chain of normal subgroups of G, that are also subgroups of (and hence normal in) $H$, and that don't satisfy min$H$ and take the smallest of those (using min-$n$ on $G$.)

By the way it's asserted so casually, I assume "not min-$n$" should immediately imply "not min$H$" and so $H$-admissible on a subset of $H$ should immediately imply normality in $H$ (for then every $H$-admissible chain would also be a chain of normal subgroups of H.)  But that it shouldn't be equivalent to normality in $H$ (because then, why would he bother to use it.)

So suppose $A\le G$, what does it mean for $A$ to be $H$-admissible?

I believe that if $A\le H$ then "$A$ is $H$-admissible" $\implies A\lhd H$ but not the converse.

I assume that $H$ is considered to act somehow on subgroups, analogous to $\Omega$-admissible.  I considered two possible conditions (i) $HA=AH$ and (ii) $HA = A$.  But if $A\le H$ the first is always true (since $H\lhd G$) and the second true only when $A=H$ so neither seems useful as a definition of $H$-admissible.

I'm stuck.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, or likely made a logical mistake. Or both.

Comment: Wouldn't it just mean "closed under conjugation by elements of $H$"? That's the obvious way for $H$ to act on subgroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok, so for a subgroup A of H that's equivalent to "A is normal in H".  Then "minH" for H is identical to "min-n" for H.  Yes, I see, and even if we are focusing on subgroups K of H, "min-n" is a stronger condition than "minH" because what's normal in K might not be normal in H, and that's why he needs the terminology "minH" for the next part of the proof.  Thank you!!